# Subset row in df after the first row containing a specific value

Tags: r

Hello I have a df such as

```
COL1 COL2 
A OKI
B OKO
C OKU
D OKP
E BRUT
F 0.87
G 0.82
H 0.57
```

and I would like to subset the df for all line after the `"BRUT"` row

and get :

```
COL1 COL2 
F 0.87
G 0.82
H 0.57
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `which.max` to get row number for first value of "BRUT".

```
df[(which.max(df$COL2 == 'BRUT') + 1):nrow(df), ]

#  COL1 COL2
#6    F 0.87
#7    G 0.82
#8    H 0.57
```

Some other options comparing with row number :

```
df[seq_len(nrow(df)) > which.max(df$COL2 == 'BRUT'), ]
```

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(row_number() > which.max(COL2 == 'BRUT'))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(COL1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"
), COL2 = c("OKI", "OKO", "OKU", "OKP", "BRUT", "0.87", "0.82", 
"0.57")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `match` to get the line with *BRUT*, add 1 and create a sequence until `nrow(x)` to subset `x` to get all lines after *BRUT*.

```
x[(match("BRUT", x$COL2)+1):nrow(x),]
#  COL1 COL2
#6    F 0.87
#7    G 0.82
#8    H 0.57
```

Or using `tail`, as suggested by @thelatemail (Thanks!).

```
tail(x, -match("BRUT",x$COL2))
```

Or some other alternatives:

```
x[-(1:match("BRUT", x$COL2)),]
x[-seq_len(match("BRUT", x$COL2)),]
```

Comment: Alternative using `match` is to `tail` to remove the rows once you get the index - `tail(x, -match("BRUT",x$COL2))`

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks! I have added this.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you only want the numeric values. In this case a more robust solution can be,

```
 df[grepl('[0-9]', df$COL2),]

#  COL1 COL2
#6    F 0.87
#7    G 0.82
#8    H 0.57
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `cumsum` in `base R`

```
subset(df, cumsum(cumsum(COL2 == "BRUT")) >1)
#  COL1 COL2
#6    F 0.87
#7    G 0.82
#8    H 0.57
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(COL1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"
), COL2 = c("OKI", "OKO", "OKU", "OKP", "BRUT", "0.87", "0.82", 
"0.57")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```